# computed selected field not present in response

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have this model in `gorm` with 2 fields which I do not want inside the table as they are computed from the sql query:

```
type User struct {
    ID          uint        `json:"id" gorm:"primarykey,autoIncrement"`
    MutedUsers     []*User `json:"-" gorm:"many2many:user_muted_users;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    BlockedUsers   []*User `json:"-" gorm:"many2many:user_blocked_users;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    ...

    IsMuted     bool `json:"is_muted" gorm:"-"`
    IsBlocked   bool `json:"is_blocked" gorm:"-"`
}
```

Query which computes above fields:

```
var users []models.User

userMutedQ := database.Instance.
    Table("user_muted_users").
    Select("1").
    Where("user_id = ? and muted_user_id = u.id", 1)

userBlockedQ := database.Instance.
    Table("user_blocked_users").
    Select("1").
    Where("user_id = ? and blocked_user_id = u.id", 1)

database.Instance.
    Table("users u").
    Select("u.*, "+
        "(case when exists(?) then 'true' else 'false' end) as is_muted, "+
        "(case when exists(?) then 'true' else 'false' end) as is_blocked, ",
        userMutedQ, userBlockedQ, 
    ).
    Where("u.id = 1").
    Scan(&users)
```

The sql from the console, when run against the database will produce columns with the right value for `is_muted` `is_blocked` (some `true` some `false`).

The `users` list however, have all values for `is_muted` `is_blocked` to false. Maybe `gorm` is ignoring them due to the `-` flag definition. If I don't use `-` then `gorm` will create `is_muted` `is_blocked` columns inside my database which are totally redundant since the value is always computed.

What is the right way here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to **docs** ([Declaring Models/Field-Level Permission](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Field-Level-Permission)) and **new feature** ([Add field tag to ignore migration](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/pull/4028) and [PR](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/pull/4028/commits/8771f3c27c1fb73b4b1a21cf706f6d81819b9f41)), you can use `migration` directive for `-` tag to ignore field creation during [migration](https://gorm.io/docs/migration.html#Auto-Migration) and use `->` to *readonly* field permission:

```
IsBlocked bool `gorm:"->;-:migration"`
```

Comment: Solid, did my own research before posting but I didn't find that info.

Comment: The bad part is that gorm will try to populate those fields on every read on that table  which will fail `ERROR:  column users.is_muted does not exist`.

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea - I tried use `Find`/`Select`/`First` with `gorm:"->;-:migration"` tag   works fine... add your code snippet

Comment: The fact that you mentioned `Find/Select/First` got me thinking so I tool a look and I was using `Scan`, don't ask me why - maybe from trying too many wrong things. Without scan (`Find`) works allright. Thanks.

Comment: But it doesn't work when the table is pulled as a relation with something like `usersAssoc := database.Instance.Model(chat).Association("Users")`. The calling will make gorm say the field `is_blocked` does not exist on table users. I pulled those fields from the model and created a new struct with them and an inheritance from the user's model. Can't find a more elegant way atm.

Comment: Issue created with reproducible code and tests: https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/4698